# type cast char to Unsigned short

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert the characters to unsigned short but the value I'm getting in m_cmdCode is always 0. Some input would be very helpful.

```
int main()
{
 char *temp = new char[3];
 memset(temp,1,3);
 unsigned short m_cmdCode = (unsigned short) atoi(temp);
 printf("%d",m_cmdCode);
}
```

// I want m_cmdCode to be equal to 111, is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 7):

You're setting the elements of `temp` to the integer value `1`. You want the character value `'1'`:

```
memset(temp, '1', 3);
```

Note that you also need to NUL-terminate `temp` for `atoi` to work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

it's come from your memset, you put 3 bytes with value 1 it's not the same thing than writing

```
strcpy(temp, "111")
```

maybe I reversed the src and dest

Comment: This will attempt to write a terminator and thus overflow the allocated array.