# Character array typecasting to integer

Tags: c++, c

I have a char array and it holds value 0x4010, i want this value into an unsigned short varaible.
I did this by using atoi but getting short value as 0

```
unsigned short cvtValue = (unsigned short) atoi(aclDta);
```

character for 0x10 is DEL, i hope it is because of this.
Decimal is 6416

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast`

Comment: possible duplicate of [type cast char to Unsigned short](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430067/type-cast-char-to-unsigned-short)

Comment: how can a char array hold a value 0x4010? that's bigger than a char. Does it hold the string "0x4010". or is byte 0 0x40 and byte 1 0x10. or possibly vice-versa depending on your architecture?

Comment: Understand that you have a sequence of 8-bit numeric values which are currently present in a piece of storage that is aliased by a `char*` pointer.  They are not, in any real sense, "characters".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to *convert* the data with `atoi`, just cast it:

```
unsigned short cvtValue = *(unsigned short *)aclDta;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking doesn't make sense. 0x4010 in ascii is '@' followed by a 'data link escape'.

atoi, strtol etc are all about parsing ascii strings containing numbers - `@\DLE` isn't a number.

What you really seem to want is to treat the 0x4010 bytes as a single short.

here's a cheap way:

```
cvtValue |= ((short)aclData[0]) << 8;
cvtValue |= ((short)aclData[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd comment, but apparently as a new user I can't?  Anyway, antiduh's answer is more correct if you might ever port your application to platforms having different endienness.

```
char *str = "01";
unsigned short val = *(unsigned short *)str;
```

On little endien systems val == 0x3130.  On big endien systems val == 0x3031.

Comment: Well hear is somthing to get you started+1